# SQL Injection modify table

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, security, sql-injection

I am doing an exercise in class to find web page vulnerabilities through a user/password form and we are suppouse to be able to modify columns of a table using SQL injection.

I know the tables of the database, for instance I am trying to modify the table users that has the colums id, password and email.

The problem is that for INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE the server code use the executeUpdate() method and for SELECT use the executeQuery() method which returns the ResultSet, so obviusly when I try someting like:

`correctpassword'; UPDATE usuarios SET id='newname' WHERE id='oldname'; --`

it returns an error because UPDATE does not return the ResultSet object.

I have also tried nested queries so the main consult would be a SELECT so it would actually return a ResultSet object but it doesnt work either. The query is:

`correctpassword'; SELECT id FROM usuarios WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM usuarios WHERE id=?admin?; UPDATE usuarios SET id=?luciareina? WHERE id=?admin?); --`

Do you know anyway to do this? Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the database server you have, you can not have an update statement inside of a select statement.

you should close out the existing query and then do the update
Also, make sure the column you are updating is not an auto generated/key column that is not updatable.

`SELECT id FROM usuarios WHERE id = 1; UPDATE usuarios SET id=1 WHERE id=2`

You should test your injection directly on server to see if it is valid before testing it via the webpage.